# Profile image gallery provided by database

Tags: image, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-5, user-profile

I'm currently working on profile images for my registered users.

As of now my users can upload their own images to use and of course there's a default image, incase users don't upload a picture.
By the way, I'm using the Paperclip gem.

I've been trying to do so that my users can choose to select an image from a list of images, provided by the website/database.

This website: https://satwcomic.com/ has exactly what I'm looking for.
[Example from the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLgdp.png).

I've been trying to find a solution for this for the past month, but without luck. any hints on how i could successfully achieve such feature with or without paperclip? 
I'm hoping to get pushed in the right direction.

Please do keep in mind, I'm still learning Ruby on Rails as a student and any help will be appriciated.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @SeanHuber wondering how i can achieve a similar feature with or without paperclip